# Textarea ou textbox dependente de um select

Tags: javascript, html

Olá pessoal sou iniciante na área e preciso fazer um textarea ou textbox dependente de um select (campo Motivo)  ou seja toda vez que o select selecionar um iten da lista ele preenche  o campo textarea ou textbox ( campo Acao) com a resposta dependente ( estou usando javascrip e html) carregando os dados de uma planilha sheets ( lista grande) para dependência fiz em forma de lista como está abaixo e ele faz a dependência  porém não quero o campo Acao  em lista e sim textbox mas quando mudo para textbox ele não faz a dependência com o campo Motivo. .. alguém pode me orientar (ajudar) ? Grata

Html:
document.getElementById("Motivo").addEventListener("input", ListaAcao);

```
     function ListaAcao(){
   
           var comboAcao = document.getElementById("Acao");
           
           while (comboAcao.length){
               comboAcao.remove(0); 
           }
               
           var ListaAcao =  document.getElementById("Acao");                    
           var TextoAcao = "Escolha uma Ação"                   
           var NovaOpcaoAcao = document.createElement("option");
           var TextoNovaOpcaoAcao = document.createTextNode(TextoAcao);
               
           NovaOpcaoAcao.appendChild(TextoNovaOpcaoAcao);
               
           ListaAcao.insertBefore(NovaOpcaoAcao, ListaAcao.lastChild);
               
           document.getElementById("Acao").options[0].disabled = true;
           
           var Motivo =  document.getElementById("Motivo").value;
           
           google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Carregar).Acao(Motivo);
        
          
            function Carregar(Acao){
   
               if (Acao != "MOTIVO NÃO ENCONTRADO"){
               
                   var ListaAcao =  document.getElementById("Acao");
                   
                       Acao.forEach(function(r){
                   
                            var TextoAcao = r[0];
                           
                            var NovaOpcaoAcao = document.createElement("option");
                            var TextoNovaOpcaoAcao = document.createTextNode(TextoAcao);
                           
                            NovaOpcaoAcao.appendChild(TextoNovaOpcaoAcao);
                           
                            ListaAcao.insertBefore(NovaOpcaoAcao, ListaAcao.lastChild); 
                       
                       });                                       
               }                             
            }           
      }
```

Javascript

function Acao(Motivo) {

var Planilha = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var Guia = Planilha.getSheetByName("Listas");
var LocalPesquisa = Guia.getRange(2, 27, 1, Guia.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

var Resultado = LocalPesquisa.Pesquisa(Motivo);

if (Resultado !=-1){

var Coluna = Resultado + 27

Guia.getRange(3, Coluna).activate();
Guia.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();

var QtdLinha =  Guia.getCurrentCell().getRow();
var QtdLinha = QtdLinha - 2

var Dados = Guia.getRange(3, Coluna, QtdLinha).getValues();

return Dados;

}else{

return 'MOTIVO NÃO ENCONTRADO'

}

}

Array.prototype.Pesquisa = function(Procura){

if (Procura == "") return false;

for ( var Linha = 0; Linha<this.length; Linha ++)

if (this[Linha] == Procura) return Linha;

return - 1

}

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que eu entendi você quer colocar um select e que ao selecionar um item deste select o autocomplete/autofill do textbox vai colocar no datalist certos valores.

Js e depois o Html respectivamente

```js
function change() {
    var select = document.getElementById("select").value
    document.getElementById("textbox").setAttribute('list', select)
    
}
```

```html
<form>
    <select onchange="change()" name="select" id="select">
        <option value="valor1" selected>Valor 1</option> 
        <option value="valor2">Valor 2</option>
        <option value="valor3">Valor 3</option>
    </select>
    <input id="textbox" type="text" size="20" list="valor1">

    <datalist id="valor1">
        <option value="1.25"></option>
        <option value="1.5"></option>
        <option value="1.75"></option>
    </datalist>

    
    <datalist id="valor2">
        <option value="2.25"></option>
        <option value="2.5"></option>
        <option value="2.75"></option>
    </datalist>

    
    <datalist id="valor3">
        <option value="3.25"></option>
        <option value="3.5"></option>
        <option value="3.75"></option>
    </datalist>

</form>
```

No HTML tem o valor das opções do select no caso são "valor1", "valor2" e "valor3" coloquei para que já venha selecionado o "valor1" e você pode notar que o list do input também vem com o "valor1". Fiz 3 datalist com os nomes dos values das options do select para dar menos trabalho ao for selecionar o item, ao alterar o select ele vai executar a função change(), que vai denominar o valor do select em uma variavel chamada select, após isso ele vai pegar o atributo 'list' (para alterar o datalist) e vai alterar para o valor do select ("valor1", "valor2"... que corresponde aos ids dos datalist), por isso coloquei o id dos datalists igual o value do select assim vai automaticamente selecionar o datalist correspondente ao valor do select.

Espero ter ajudado ;)

Comment: Muito bom deu certo usei essa metodologia um pouco diferente do que eu precisava mas deu certo  e funcionou obrigada